# How to properly store name of directories into a linked list?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, singly-linked-list, c-strings

I'm trying to store the names of directories and sub directories in a linked list. When I display them using `printf`, the names are listed correctly, but when I try to store them in a linked list they do not appear correctly.

Every thing works when when I'm just printing, but results differ when I store the strings into a linked list and displaying it.

```
void ls_r(char *path) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *file;
    struct stat buf;
    char *temp;
    t_list *list;

    if (!(dir = opendir(path)))
        return;
    list = NULL;
    while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (file->d_name[0] != '.') {
            temp = strdup(path);
            strcat(temp, "/");
            strcat(temp, file->d_name);
            stat(temp, &buf);
            if (buf.st_mode && S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
                ft_list_insert(&list, temp);
                printf("%s\n", temp);
                ls_r(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    ft_print_list(list, "\n");
}
```

`printf` result:

```
./file3
./file3/file32
./file3/file33
./file3/file31
./file3/file31/file311
./file3/file31/file313
./file3/file31/file312
./file2
./file1
./file1/file11
./file1/file12
./file1/file13
```

linked list result:

```
./file3/file31/f .@��
./file3/file31/f�-@��
./file3/file31/f./file3/file31
./file3/file33
./file3/file32./file1/file13
./file1/file12
./file1/file11./file1
./file2
./file3
```

Comment: This statement  temp = strdup(path); does not guarantee that the memory pointed to by temp has enough space to append other strings like strcat(temp, "/");.

Comment: And what does this function ls_r(temp); do?

Answer (score 2):

These statements

```
        temp = strdup(path);
        strcat(temp, "/");
        strcat(temp, file->d_name);
```

are invalid.

You have to reserve enough space to contain the concatenation of strings `path`, `"/"`, and `file->d_name`.

So use for example

```
temp = malloc( strlen( path ) + sizeof( ( char )'/' ) + strlen( file->d_name ) + sizeof( ( char )'\0' ) );
```

and then copy the strings into the allocated memory.

```
strcpy( temp, path );
strcat(temp, "/");
strcat(temp, file->d_name);
```

Also it is possible that the function `ft_list_insert` the code of which is not shown does not correctly insert a node in the list.

Comment: `char` size is `1` by definition.  Why not write `2` instead of `sizeof( ( char )'/' ) + sizeof( ( char )'\0' ))` which is rather cryptic?

Comment: @chqrlie Because it is self-documented.

Comment: I understand your argument, but the sad fact that `'/'` has type `int` in C as opposed to type `char` in C++ makes the cast `(char)'/'` necessary and the whole expression difficult to interpret for newbies. More advanced programmers would probably not need the self documentation.  Furthermore you are adding a number of `char`, returned by `strlen` with the size of a `char`, making the implicit assumption that `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Comment: @chqrlie sizeof( char ) is indeed equal to 1. So what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is consistency and readability: Adding `sizeof(char)` may induce newbies into thinking that is may differ from `1` on some architectures. java programmers might even consider it logical since a `char` is indeed 2 bytes in that languages.

Comment: @chqrlie As I said the statement is very clear and self-documented. Otherwise you have to add a comment that who is reading code should understand what the magic number 2 means. My code does not have any magic numbers.

Comment: @chqrlie Moreover looking at the arguments of the call of malloc it is visible at once what string is being built.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behavior because you copy extra characters at the end of the string allocated by `strdup`. You must allocate enough space for the complete string.

Note also that you have a memory leak for all entries that are not directories, and you should free the list before returning too. The path should be freed too if `ft_list_insert()` duplicates it.

Also testing `buf.st_mode` seems useless, but testing for `stat` failure is necessary to avoid reading uninitialized contents of the `buf` structure.

Here is a modified version with a utility function:

```c
char *makepath(const char *dir, const char *name) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(dir);
    size_t len2 = strlen(name);
    // allocate extra space for '/' and '\0'
    size size = len1 + len2 + 2;
    char *p = malloc(size);
    if (p != NULL) {
        // copy the directory part
        memcpy(p, dir, len1);
        if (len1 > 0 && dir[len - 1] != '/') {
            // only append a path separator if needed
            p[len1++] = '/';
        }
        // copy the filename and its null terminator
        memcpy(p + len1, name, len2 + 1);
    }
    return p;
}

void ls_r(const char *path) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *file;
    struct stat buf;
    char *temp;
    t_list *list;

    if (!(dir = opendir(path)))
        return;
    list = NULL;
    while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (file->d_name[0] != '.') {
            temp = makepath(path, file->d_name);
            if (temp != NULL && !stat(temp, &buf) && S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
                ft_list_insert(&list, temp);
                printf("%s\n", temp);
                ls_r(temp);
            } else {
                free(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    ft_print_list(list, "\n");
    ft_free_list(list);  // assuming ft_free_list() also frees the list payload
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

**Changes:** (Done on top of @chqrlie changes)

1. Added main function to call ls_r() function.
2. Allocated heap memory for "char *temp" before writing actual path to the same memory location.
3. Added singly linked list utility functions to maintain the directory list.
4. removed ft_print_list(list, "\n"); call from ls_r() as it getting called recursively. Moved the same call with different function name (print_list()) to the main function.

Basically, you need to take care of memory allocations and deallocations properly. Otherwise, you encounter these kind of problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

/* directory node structure */
struct dir_node
{
    char *path;
    struct dir_node *next;
};

typedef struct dir_node dnode;

/* Global pointers, these can be moved to main() function
 * and can be passed to the required functions.
 * To do that you will have to use double pointers(pointer to pointer).
 * Just for understanding making these as global.
 */

dnode *newnode,*temp;
dnode *list = NULL, *last = NULL;

/*
 * Creating new node.
 */
dnode* create_node(char* path)
{
    newnode = (dnode *)malloc(sizeof(dnode));
    if (newnode == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nMemory was not allocated");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        int path_len = strlen(path);
        //make sure we have received valid path.
        if(path_len <= 0)
        {
            free(newnode);
            newnode=NULL;
            return NULL;
        }
        newnode->path = path;
        newnode->next = NULL;
        return newnode;
    }
}
/*
 * Insert new node at the end of the list.
 */
void insert_node(char* path)
{
    newnode = create_node(path);
    if(newnode == NULL)
    {
        //Something went wrong.
        //Either path is invalid or memory is not allocated properly.
        return;
    }
    if (list == last && last == NULL)
    {
        //First node in the list.
        list = last = newnode;
        list->next = NULL;
        last->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next = newnode;
        last = newnode;
        last->next = NULL;
    }
}
/*
 * Print the list.
 */
void print_list()
{
    temp=list;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",temp->path);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

}
/*
 * Clear the list.
 */
void clear_list()
{
    dnode* current = list;
    dnode* next;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        if(current->path != NULL)
        {
            free(current->path);
            current->path=NULL;
        }
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
    list = NULL;
    temp=list;
}
char *create_path(const char *dir, const char *name) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(dir);
    size_t len2 = strlen(name);
    // allocate extra space for '/' and '\0'
    size_t size = len1 + len2 + 2;
    char *p = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    if (p != NULL) {
        // copy the directory part
        memcpy(p, dir, len1);
        if (len1 > 0 && dir[len1 - 1] != '/') {
            // add a path separator if needed
            p[len1++] = '/';
        }
        // copy the filename and its null terminator
        memcpy(p + len1, name, len2 + 1);
    }
    return p;
}

void ls_r(const char *path) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *file;
    struct stat buf;
    char *temp=NULL;

    if (!(dir = opendir(path)))
        return;
    while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (file->d_name[0] != '.') {
            temp = create_path(path, file->d_name);
            if (temp != NULL && !stat(temp, &buf) && S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
                printf("%s\n", temp);
                insert_node(temp);
                ls_r(temp);
            } else {
                free(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    ls_r("/work/Workspace/");
    printf(".....Directory list:....\n");
    print_list();
    clear_list();
    printf(".....Directory list after clearing:....\n");
    print_list();
    printf("...done....\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You copied my code without attribution and failed to handle memory correctly: since your version of `insert_node()` duplicates the path, you should free it in `ls_lr()` after recursing. You should also optimize appending to the list to avoid lengthy operation in `insert_node()`. For example `insert_node()` could insert at the beginning and the list could be reversed before printing.

Comment: @chqrlie, Sorry, I thought I'll add your name as edited on top of your changes but I forgot to add. I'll not repeat the same. Yeah, the memory leak was there as I'm duplicating the path in the create_node() and now I've taken care. Regarding optimization, since I'm maintaining the last node pointer globally, insertion can be done easily without iterating again. This doesn't require printing the list again in reverse as you said.